# How do I continue development from an earlier revision?

Tags: mercurial

In my project I would like to continue development from an earlier revision. So far I have done

```
$ hg up -r REV
```

and committed a changeset. How do I "get rid of" the old branch that I'm no longer interested in so I can push the repository without the *force* option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To undo the last *N* commits (but without changing the history), do the following:

1. Revert the working directory to the desired revision:

   $ hg revert -aC -r -<N + 1>
2. Commit the changes:

   $ hg ci -m "Undo N changesets"

Now this branch can be merged with the other one.